# What is the term for a list of points that contains distinct informations kept apart with a pattern?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

I have a sorted list of points coming from a program calculating the intersections of bodies with a regular pattern of lines. After discarding the tangents, it results in a well structured list of Points P<sub>1</sub> to P<sub>n</sub> with $n\in2N ; N\in\mathbb{N}^{>0}$.

Now, each odd point P<sub>o</sub> with $o\in2N-1 ; N\in\mathbb{N}^{>0}$ does represent a "start" and each even point P<sub>e</sub> with $e\in2N+; N\in\mathbb{N}^{>0}$ represents the "end" that belongs to this and only this P<sub>o</sub>. My trouble now lies in the nomenclature:

What is the correct term for a list that contains patterned *sublists* of a specific length (here 2)?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, if the sublists are of length $2$, I would say that the list “interleaves start points and end points" or resulted from “interleaving start points and end points”; it is an “interleaved list of start and end points”.

More generally, and especially for length $\gt2$, I would say that you have “concatenated” lists to form a single list, or “flattened” a list of lists into a single list.